# passing Arraylist using Serializable

Tags: android, android-intent, serializable

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ENGLISH", english);
        startActivity(intent);
```

And it is another Activity

```
     ArrayList<Model> data = (ArrayList<Model>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ENGLISH");
```

What am I doing wrong?
Please help, I read these kind of question in here but I couldn't understand. In my view, everything true, but it gives NullPointException

Comment: Does your `Model` class implement serializable? Where are you getting the `NullPointerException`? (i.e. what is the code saying is null? Consider adding the stacktrace to your question).

Comment: Yes I emplemented it.                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: Do you have more code to share? There isn't much to debug here. If the code is not open source, can you maybe copy the relevant code into a public repo on GitHub?

Comment: the error has nothing to do with intent and data passing. It says int.java.util.List.size() that means you have not initialized the list. Do it as               `List<sample> mylist = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: show the model class . also the english arraylist intialization